# How to zoom into a stacked barplot with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to build a stacked barplot using ggplot and ggforce so that the column on the left is a zoomed version of a section of the column on the right (or vice versa). Some toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                 Status = c("Bought", "Sold", "Sold", "Sold", "Sold", "Sold"),
                 Month = c("April", "March", "May", "July", "October", "November"),
                 N = c(48, 12, 11, 1, 2, 3))
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
(chart1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Product, y =N, fill = Status))+
  geom_col(position = "stack")+
  geom_text(aes(label = N), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)))
```

With that code, I was able to build the following chart. As a first question, how do I get only one number (the sum of the other values of sold products) on the blue bar?
[image: chart1]

After that, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
(chart2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Product, y =N, fill = Month))+
  geom_col(position = "stack")+
  geom_text(aes(label = N), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw()+
  facet_zoom(ylim = c(0, 27.5)))
```

This gives me this chart:
[image: chart2 - with zoom]

The final result I expect is chart2, but the bar on the right side should be similar to the bar on chart1 (except that I want to show only one number on the blue bar: the sum of the sold products). The colors don't need to be as in the figures. In addition, is there a way to mirror the final chart so that the bar on the left appears on the right side?

If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.
Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky approach would be to use two pairs of `geom_col` and `geom_text` layers to create the main and the zoom panel plots. For the main panel plot use a summarized df where you recode the `Month` column into `"April"` and `"Other"`. For the zoom panel plot use the original dataset but drop `"April"`. Finally set `zoom.data = !Month %in% c("April", "Other")` which will prevent the "zoom" categories to be displayed in the main panel.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df |> 
  mutate(Month = ifelse(Status == "Bought", Month, "Other")) |> 
  count(Product, Month, wt = N, name = "N")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Product, y = N)) +
  geom_col(data = df1, aes(fill = Month), position = "stack") +
  geom_text(
    data = df1, aes(label = N, group = Month),
    size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  geom_col(data = ~ subset(.x, Month != "April"), aes(fill = Month), position = "stack") +
  geom_text(
    data = ~ subset(.x, Month != "April"), aes(label = N, group = Month),
    size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = unique(df$Month)) +
  facet_zoom(ylim = c(0, 27.5), zoom.data = !Month %in% c("April", "Other")) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image]

**EDIT** As an alternative approach you could fake the `facet_zoom` look using `facet_wrap` and some `geom_polygon`s. Does not look that perfect and requires some fiddling but on the other hand gives gives you more control like e.g. the positioning of the panels, the axis labels, ...

```
df1 <- df |>
  mutate(Month = ifelse(Status == "Bought", Month, "Other")) |>
  count(Product, Month, wt = N, name = "N")

df2 <- df |>
  filter(Month != "April") |>
  mutate(Product = Status)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Product, y = N)) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = data.frame(x = rep(1, 4), y = 1, Product = "A"),
    x = c(.4, 1.6, 1.6, .4),
    y = c(-1, -1, 30, 30),
    fill = "grey60", alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = data.frame(x = rep(1, 4), y = 1, Product = "Sold"),
    x = c(0.4, .625, .625, 0.4), y = c(-1 * 29 / 77, 0, 29, 30 * 29 / 77),
    fill = "grey60", alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_col(data = df1, aes(fill = Month), position = "stack", width = .75) +
  geom_text(
    data = df1, aes(label = N, group = Month),
    size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  geom_col(data = df2, aes(fill = Month), position = "stack", width = .75) +
  geom_text(
    data = df2, aes(label = N, group = Month),
    size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = unique(df$Month)) +
  facet_wrap(~Product, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(fill = NULL) +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      Product == "Sold" ~ scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @stefan! Is there a way to rename the label of the left column? I would like to change the "A" under the bar to "Sold".

Comment: In addition, when I run the following piece of code: ````facet_zoom(ylim = c(0, 27.5), zoom.data = !Month %in% c("April", "Other")````, I get an error message: Error in `vec_rbind()`:
! Can't combine `..1$x` <mapped_discrete> and `..2$x` <mapped_discrete>.
✖ Some attributes are incompatible.
ℹ The author of the class should implement vctrs methods.
ℹ See <https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/faq-error-incompatible-attributes.html>.

Comment: Hm. Just checked the code again and it runs without errors on my side. Maybe an issue with the package version? Mine are ggplot2 3.4.1, ggforce 0.4.1 and dplyr 1.1.1. Concerning your first question: Unfortunately no. But I just made an edit to show an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you, @stefan! I had some trouble with those ````geom_polygon````s, so the code didn't solve my problem as I expected. But thanks anyway!